# Float (or detach) the tabbed CMDIChildWndEx window from CMDIFrameWndEx,any idea?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc, mdi

In visual studio,all opened editor windows are tabbed in the workspace.when you right click one,there is a "float" option in the menu.if you float a window,the window is detached from the tab and you can drag it anywhere and after all you can dock it back to the tab.

i created a test mdi project,it's not a default behavior.

i overrided the ID_FILE_NEW command and followed the OpenDocumentFile routine,never found out where the framework add the newly created child frame window to the tab.

in the OpenDocumentFile routine,i bumped into a CMFCTabCtrl class and there is a AddTab function.

now the AddTab function:

```
virtual void AddTab(
   CWnd* pTabWnd,
   LPCTSTR lpszTabLabel,
   UINT uiImageId = (UINT)-1,,
   BOOL bDetachable = TRUE
);

virtual void AddTab(
   CWnd* pTabWnd,
   UINT uiResTabLabel,
   UINT uiImageId = (UINT)-1,
   BOOL bDetachable = TRUE
);
```

the Remarks:

If pTabWnd points to an object that is not derived from the CDockablePane Class and

if bDetachable is TRUE, the framework automatically creates a wrapper for the pTabWnd object.

The wrapper makes the pTabWnd object detachable.

By default, the wrapper is an instance of the CDockablePaneAdapter Class.

If the functionality offered by the default wrapper is unacceptable,

use the CMFCBaseTabCtrl::SetDockingBarWrapperRTC method to specify a different wrapper.

still no luck.

i did try to on the fly create a CView and attach it to the CDocument and put that CView in a CDockablePane.so i could switch the old tabbed one to the new dockable one. it's not working yet.

So any thoughts about floating the tabbed CMDIChildWndEx window from CMDIFrameWndEx?

Comment: *"still no luck"* - Doing what? It is not clear, what you are asking. You keep talking about fairly unrelated stuff, and finish up with the dreaded *"any thoughts?"*. Well, yes, ask a clear question, take the [tour] and read [ask].